# Convert list with nested dictionary into dictionary

Tags: python

I have data that comes thru in this format as shown below which I think is a list with nested dictionary's:

```
data = [{'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/27/CLG-MAXFLOW': 580.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/29/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1400.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/30/CLG-MAXFLOW': 918.0,  
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/6/CLG-MAXFLOW': 760.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/10/CLG-MAXFLOW': 210.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/8/CLG-MAXFLOW': 880.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/9/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1040.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/11/CLG-MAXFLOW': 700.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/13/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1030.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/14/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1030.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/15/CLG-MAXFLOW': 500.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/16/CLG-MAXFLOW': 370.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/19/CLG-MAXFLOW': 970.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/20/CLG-MAXFLOW': 560.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/21/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1410.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/23/CLG-MAXFLOW': 390.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/24/CLG-MAXFLOW': 320.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/25/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1200.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/26/CLG-MAXFLOW': 815.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/31/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1214.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/34/CLG-MAXFLOW': 735.0,  
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/36/CLG-MAXFLOW': 3000.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/37/CLG-MAXFLOW': 275.0,  
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/38/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1690.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/39/CLG-MAXFLOW': 270.0}
         , {}]
```

There is always an empty dictionary at the end that can be dropped. Can someone give me a tip on how to convert this datatype to just one dictionary so it would look like this below?

```
data = {'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/27/CLG-MAXFLOW': 580.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/29/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1400.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/30/CLG-MAXFLOW': 918.0,  
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/6/CLG-MAXFLOW': 760.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/10/CLG-MAXFLOW': 210.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/8/CLG-MAXFLOW': 880.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/9/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1040.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/11/CLG-MAXFLOW': 700.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/13/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1030.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/14/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1030.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/15/CLG-MAXFLOW': 500.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/16/CLG-MAXFLOW': 370.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/19/CLG-MAXFLOW': 970.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/20/CLG-MAXFLOW': 560.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/21/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1410.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/23/CLG-MAXFLOW': 390.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/24/CLG-MAXFLOW': 320.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/25/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1200.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/26/CLG-MAXFLOW': 815.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/31/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1214.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/34/CLG-MAXFLOW': 735.0,  
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/36/CLG-MAXFLOW': 3000.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/37/CLG-MAXFLOW': 275.0,  
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/38/CLG-MAXFLOW': 1690.0, 
         'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/39/CLG-MAXFLOW': 270.0}
```

I am trying to loop through the keys and values obviously this fails:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value)
```

fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: did you try to get only the first element? `data=data[0]`

Comment: If list contains one useful dictionary and one empty for sure, you can do `data = data[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ibrahim Berber said in the comments a simple solution is to just take `data = data[0]`. Alternatively you can just leave it and just access the dictionary you want with `data[0]` as suggested by @Leonardo Stefan, which would be my preferred method.

So, your code can just simply be changed to this:

```
for key, value in data[0].items():
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution if your data is a list with only two elements and last one is empty dict:

```
my_dict = data[0]
```

Robust solution:

```py
my_dict = {}
# iterate over your data
for entry in data:
    # iterate over keys in the dict
    for key in entry:
        my_dict[key] = entry[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

To flatten any number of dictionaries in the list into a single dictionary without relying on the first index:

```
flatten = {}
for n in data:
    flatten.update(n)
```

After creating this flattened dictionary, your code below will work just fine:

```
for key, value in flatten.items():
    print(key, value)
```